# Как сделать поиск по Json?

Tags: javascript, json

Бд в таком формате:

```
 hero1 = {
  name: "Batman",
  speed: 10,
  power: 10,
  intelligence: 10,
  strength: 20
 }
hero2 = {
  name: "Superman",
  speed: 12,
  power: 11,
  intelligence: 9,
  strength: 30  
 }
 hero3 = {
  name: "Spider man",
  speed: 30,
  power: 5,
  intelligence: 9,
  strength: 10  
 }
```

Так вот, как нам сделать поиск по имени например?
Например Если имя Spider Man то как нам получить в переменную var power = 5 ?

Comment: Так у вас база данных или просто массив героев?

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
var power = [hero1, hero2, hero3].filter(h => h.name == "Spider man")[0].power
```

Так как ваш кусок кода — не JSON, то я добавил массив. Если у вас JSON, то изменится только получение исходного массива.

Проверку ошибок добавить по вкусу.

Comment: А можнол как то что бы не прописывать все hero1, hero2, hero3 ?

Comment: @arthru Можно, но тогда надо изначально хранить данные не в отдельных переменных, а в массиве (`[ { name: "Batman", ... }, { name: "Superman", ... }, ... ]`) или объекте (`{ hero1: { name: "Batman", ... }, hero2: { name: "Superman", ... }, ... }`).

Comment: Хорошо если мы будем хранить их в масиве, как тогда сделать поиск?

Comment: @arthru Тогда замените кусок `[hero1, hero2, hero3]` на имя вашего массива.